# Can I select arbitrary windows from the last dimension of a numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I'd like to write a numpy function that takes an MxN array `A`, a window length `L`, and an MxP array `idxs` of starting indices into the `M` rows of `A` that selects `P` arbitrary slices of length `L` from each of the M rows of `A`. Except, I would love for this to work on the last dimension of `A`, and not necessarily care how many dimensions `A` has, so all dims of `A` and `idxs` match except the last one. Examples:

If `A` is just 1D:

```py
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

window_len = 3

idxs = np.array([1, 3])

result = magical_routine(A, idxs, window_len)
```

Where `result` is a 2x3 array since I selected 2 slices of len 3:

```py
np.array([[ 2, 3, 4],
          [ 4, 5, 6]])
```

If A is 2D:

```py
A = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              [ 7, 8, 9,10,11,12],
              [13,14,15,16,17,18]])

window_len = 3
idxs = np.array([[1, 3],
                 [0, 1],
                 [2, 2]])

result = magical_routine(A, idxs, window_len)
```

Where `result` is a 3x2x3 array since there are 3 rows of `A`, and I selected 2 slices of len 3 from each row:

```py
np.array([[[ 2, 3, 4], [ 4, 5, 6]],
          [[ 7, 8, 9], [ 8, 9,10]],
          [[15,16,17], [15,16,17]]])
```

And so on.

I have discovered an number of inefficient ways to do this, along with ways that work for a specific number of dimensions of `A`. For 2D, the following is pretty tidy:

```py
col_idxs = np.add.outer(idxs, np.arange(window_len))
np.take_along_axis(A[:, np.newaxis], col_idxs, axis=-1)
```

I can't see a nice way to generalize this for 1D and other D's though...

Is anyone aware of an efficient way that generalizes to any number of dims?

Comment: Take a look at np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view

Comment: I don't want a sliding window. I want arbitrary windows that can be anywhere within the array, not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: But is the size consistent?  You can just index of a subset of the windows.  Anyways, I'd suggest adding one or more of those "inefficient" ways to your question.  I suspect `sliding-window` is the closest you'll get of magical function.

Comment: Are you aware that you can index the last dimension with something like `x[...,1:4]`?

Comment: @hpaulj I am aware, but in higher dimensions than 1 that seems to mean I have to build up specific selections for all the other dimensions as well, and it gets quite ugly. I am struggling to find a clean route in that direction. I also run into similar problems with `take`

Comment: It's also quite acceptable to create a list or array containing slices etc, convert to a tuple and use it for indexing.  If it looks too ugly, hide it in a function.

Comment: @hpaulj, don't know if it will help, but added an example of a nice way to do 2D, but I haven't quite figured out how to nicely generalize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I was almost there:

```py
def magical_routine(A, idxs, window_len=2000):
    col_idxs = np.add.outer(idxs, np.arange(window_len))
    return np.take_along_axis(A[..., np.newaxis, :], col_idxs, axis=-1)
```

I just needed to always add the new axis to A's second to last dim, and then leave remaining axes alone.

Comment: `take_along` does what we used todo with `np.arange(n)[:,None]` indexing (and I still do)

Answer (score 0):

For your 1d case

```
In [271]: A=np.arange(1,7)
In [272]: idxs = np.array([1,3])
```

Using the kind of iteration that this questions usually gets:

```
In [273]: np.vstack([A[i:i+3] for i in idxs])
Out[273]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Alternatively generate all indices, and one indexing.  `linspace` is handy for this (though it's not the only option):

```
In [278]: j = np.linspace(idxs,idxs+3,3,endpoint=False)
In [279]: j
Out[279]: 
array([[1., 3.],
       [2., 4.],
       [3., 5.]])
In [282]: A[j.T.astype(int)]
Out[282]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

for the 2d

```
In [284]: B
Out[284]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])

In [285]: idxs = np.array([[1, 3],
     ...:                  [0, 1],
     ...:                  [2, 2]])

In [286]: j = np.linspace(idxs,idxs+3,3,endpoint=False)

In [287]: j
Out[287]: 
array([[[1., 3.],
        [0., 1.],
        [2., 2.]],

       [[2., 4.],
        [1., 2.],
        [3., 3.]],

       [[3., 5.],
        [2., 3.],
        [4., 4.]]])
```

With a bit  of trial and error, pair up the indices to get:

```
In [292]: B[np.arange(3)[:,None,None],j.astype(int).transpose(1,2,0)]
Out[292]: 
array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [ 8,  9, 10]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

Or iterate as in the first case, but with an extra layer:

```
In [294]: np.array([[B[j,i:i+3] for i in idxs[j]] for j in range(3)])
Out[294]: 
array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [ 8,  9, 10]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

With sliding windows:

```
In [295]: aa = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(A,3)

In [296]: aa.shape
Out[296]: (4, 3)

In [297]: aa
Out[297]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [298]: aa[[1,3]]
Out[298]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

and

```
In [300]: bb = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(B,(1,3))

In [301]: bb.shape
Out[301]: (3, 4, 1, 3)

In [302]: bb[np.arange(3)[:,None],idxs,0,:]
Out[302]: 
array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [ 8,  9, 10]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```